# How to run different animation on the same object in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to run two different animation on the same div by clicking on it. 
It's a very simple div like a box

```
<div id='box'>Move me!</div>
```

css is:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #box {
        position:relative;
        width: 250px;
        height: 180px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #b3c8d0;
        border: 1px solid black;
        font-size: 16pt;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Here is the jquery I use to move it:

```
$(function() {
    $("#box").click(function() {
            $("#box").animate({ left: "500", fontSize: "24pt",  width: "500px", 
                            top: '200px' }, 1000, "swing");            
            });
        });
```

Here is a link to make it a bit clearer: http://jsfiddle.net/yy8jnc9f/

And it's working fine but that's only the first part. My problem is I would like to be able to put the div back to where it was by clicking on it.

Is there a way to do it using the animate function on the same object in jquery?

Comment: Several ways to reset it , show the initial animation code

Comment: As is nearly always the case here on StackOverflow, if you show us your current code, we are much, much more likely to be able to offer a good answer.